# want to redirect to another page from colorbox iframe after closing it

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe, colorbox

Does anyone know how to implement the following JavaScript process?
I`m using colorbox to display iframe.

1. I setted the banner link on colorbox iframe.
2. I want this iframe to close when the banner is clicked, after that I want the parent window to redirect to another page.

following 2 codes are what I`ve tried:

```
1
<div>  
<a href='#' onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close();linkto();'>
<img src="../images/test.png" alt=“#” >
</a>
<script>
function linkto() {
location.href = "https://www.test.com";
}
</script>
</div>

2
<div>  
<a href='#' onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close(); window.location.href ='https://www.test.com;'>
<img src="../images/test.png" alt=“#” >
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.top.location.href to target the top most window element and redirect to the specified page. This can be done from within an`iframe`.

HTML:

```
<a href='#' onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close(); linkTo();">
```

JS:

```
function linkTo() {
    window.top.location.href = "https://www.test.com";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: I`ll try it as soon as possible :)

Comment: Thank you for your help Alexander, I`ve confirmed it went well:)

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer that helped solve your issue. Thanks!